# Using Low Search with a custom date range

Tags: low-search

I'm trying to add 2 text fields in Low Search for users to select a beginning and end date for an event search. I'm basing my events off of entry_date instead of a custom field (though I could run a custom field if it's easier).

```
    <label for="start_on">From</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="From" name="start_on">

    <label for="stop_before">To</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="To" name="stop_before">
```

When I enter my dates (currenty being returned in YYYY-MM-DD format, search results return nothing. I'm feeling a bit lost on how to get low search to read my start_on and stop_before limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `start_on` and `stop_before` parameters need this format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`, as per [the native docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on). If you make sure the fields are in that format before the form is submitted, it should work.

Comment: Got stuck on this one too!